# Multiple textures turn to pink

Tags: texturing, shaders

I've downloaded a blender file off Sketch-fab and I knew it was created with an older version of blender. I opened the file and every texture except for some blue emission thing.[image: Textures turn to pink in Eevee and Cycles]

Answer (score 0):

Pink texture basically means that the texture is missing. I guess this file doesn't contain these textures.
EDIT: I downloaded this model, and there is separate textures folder.